# IP Range inclusion from tange

Tags: ip

the IP range written in this way:

10.27.0.0/16

means that the address

10.27.24.152

is included?

Thanks a lot.

Luigi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, 10.27.24.152 is included in your IP range (between your host min and your host max), you can use tools like this one to check by yourself : http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.27.0.0&mask1=16&mask2=

[image: Range Analysis]

Comment: Thank you Teroaz. But the /16, what does it mean?